# SQL Query for searching for a specific part of a string in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search for a specific part of a nvarchar text string in a column.

The text string is structured like this `X#2016-06-17#7483631#2016-06-27#2#167890##920`, it's split up by `#`.  I want to find 6th text block, `167890` in this case.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Which version you have?

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps with a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('X#2016-06-17#7483631#2016-06-27#2#167890##920')

Select SomeCol
      ,Pos6 = cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,'#','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[6]','varchar(50)')
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                                         Pos6
X#2016-06-17#7483631#2016-06-27#2#167890##920   167890
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SPLIT function, returning each part with an index like below:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StringSplit_WithIndex] (@str_in VARCHAR(8000),@separator VARCHAR(4) ) RETURNS @strtable TABLE (strval VARCHAR(8000),rn INT IDENTITY(1,1)) AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @Occurrences INT,
    @Counter INT,
    @tmpStr VARCHAR(8000)

    SET @Counter = 0
    IF SUBSTRING(@str_in,LEN(@str_in),1) <> @separator
        SET @str_in = @str_in + @separator
    SET @Occurrences = (DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@str_in,@separator,@separator+'#')) - DATALENGTH(@str_in))/ DATALENGTH(@separator)
    SET @tmpStr = @str_in
    WHILE @Counter <= @Occurrences
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
        INSERT INTO @strtable
        VALUES ( SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,1,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)-1))
        SET @tmpStr = SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)+1,8000)
        IF DATALENGTH(@tmpStr) = 0
        BREAK
    END

    RETURN
 END
```

Then, all you need to use the "rn" field after splitting like:

```
 DECLARE @s VARCHAR(255) = 'X#2016-06-17#7483631#2016-06-27#2#167890##920'
 SELECT * 
 FROM [StringSplit_WithIndex](@s,'#') 
 WHERE rn=6
```

Comment: Looping for splitting strings is a terrible way to go about it. Of course most of the splitters out there don't have ordinal position. Fortunately Jeff Moden put together the DelimitedSplit8K function several years ago. Then it was improved with some new advancements in sql server by Eirikur Eiriksson. Try this one out instead of that while loop. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2

Comment: Thanks @Sean, great article